# PROMPT_COMMAND not working in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to execute a specific function after each command from the script is executed. With the following example, `PROMPT_COMMAND` doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo Yes"
echo 1
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: The prompt command is associated with showing a prompt, which is inherently an interactive thing - but you're running a non-interactive script.

Comment: Is there a way to do that running a non-interactive script.

Comment: You could set a trap for the `DEBUG` pseudo event: `trap 'echo "Yes"' DEBUG` somewhere?

Comment: I need it to execute after, not before every command